# Caching images sent with response->file() in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I've implemented a media view to server otherwise protected images. A controller handles the request and checks for permissions and servers the file with `$this->response->file` accordingly.

However, I haven't managed to get the images cached, forcing the browser to always redownload (I know this from Firebug's Net panel). These files are unlikely to ever change and so caching would speed thing up considerably.

I've played around with using `$this->response->modified()` and `cache()` but to no avail.

How can i implement a check in the controller action to server either the file or not modified status code? Or am I way off here?

Any help is appreciated! :)

```
public function view($id)
{
    $this->loadModel('Image');
    $res = $this->Image->hasAccess($id, $this->Auth->user('subject_id'));

    if($res['access'] || $this->isAdmin()){
        $modified =  gmdate("D, j M Y G:i:s ", filemtime ( APP . "Content/Images/" . $res['file']));
        $this->response->modified($modified);
        $this->response->expires(time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 31);

        $this->response->file( APP . "Content/Images/" . $res['file']);

    }else if($res['access'] === false){
        $this->response->statusCode(403);
    }else if($res['access'] === null){
        $this->response->statusCode(404);
    }

   return $this->response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CakeResponse::modified()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeResponse%3a%3amodified) to set the modification time of the file, and then check whether the user agent has a valid cached version of your file using [`CakeResponse::checkNotModified()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeResponse%3a%3acheckNotModified).

```
$response->modified(filemtime($file));
if($response->checkNotModified($this->request))
{
    return $response;
}
```

See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#the-last-modified-header

Answer (score 2):

I think that better solution is add headers in you vhost file, example If you use nginx:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
  expires 1y;
  log_not_found off;
}
```

This solution it's better because next time nginx not use php to send file to user.

Comment: Good advice though if the response comes out of php, it won't apply since the webserver isn't the thing sending the response. For static files equivalent rules for most webservers can be found under the [html5 boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp) project - as well as other best practices.

Comment: Correction [after reading info that I probably wrote myself](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/conf/expires.conf#L4-L5) my previous comment is wrong :). Given that +1